# Storing value in a dynamically defined Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm writing a script that will split the element's ID from the format 'note-1192' (for example) and place it into an array:

```
    var timers = new Array();

    $('.notes').keyup(function(){

        var timerVariable = $(this).attr('id').split("-");
        timerVariable = timerVariable[0];
        timerVariable = timerVariable.replace('note', '');
        alert(timerVariable); // 1192

        timers[timerVariable] = timerVariable;
        alert(timers.join('\n')); // blank

    });
```

It's not storing the variable into the array at all, when I alert the 'timers array' it's empty, but when I alert the 'timerVariable' it comes out just fine.

Any suggestions would be very welcome, thanks!

Comment: are you sure its blank? because by inserting at index 1192, you are making 1191 undefined spots before your entry. which means when you `join()` there are going to a *a lot* of empty lines before your data.

Comment: Based on the first 4 lines of your function, if timerVariable = 'note-1192', alert(timerVariable) will never show 1192. The first index of the array timerVariable[0] will contain 'note' which will be replaced with '' after this line: timerVariable = timerVariable.replace('note', '').

Comment: Hold on. `var timerVariable = $(this).attr('id').split("-");` so now `timerVariable` is an array, with 'note' at position 0 and '1192' at position 1. Then, `timerVariable = timerVariable[0];` so now `timerVariable` is just 'note'. How did you end up with 1192 when you alerted?

Comment: The [sample code](http://sscce.org/) is neither complete, nor concise nor (if the comment is to be believed) representative. If you had produced a complete, concise, representative sample, you probably would have spotted the error.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the index syntax your are using is setting a named property on the array object not adding an element.  To add an element to the array use `push`

```
timers.push(timerVariable);
```

Comment: i am pretty sure that `a["1"]` and `a[1]` are the same. but i'm willing to be wrong on that.

Comment: but you are right that a[" 1"] != a[1], so i'm gonna go with a +1, given that its not a requirement to insert at the specific timer index.

Comment: @32bitkid yes that's true. The index of an array with a number as a string works just fine.  In this case though the OP is using a value which is not expressable as a number

Comment: Many thanks, this works perfectly, I think - I'm not sure if my array is at fault, or the code that calls it, becuase this code isn't clearing the timer correctly - http://pastebin.com/E6ABCa6J

Comment: Array indices are strings, not numbers. `a["1"]` is the actual result of doing `a[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

try

**Array:**

```
var timers = new Array();
timers.push(timerVariable);
```

**Hash:**

```
var timers = {};
timers[timerVariable] = timerVariable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `push` method of array to add an element to array.

```
timers.push(timerVariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timers = new Array();

$('.notes').keyup(function(){
    timers.push($(this).attr('id').split("-")[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the assertion in the comment,

```
"note-1192".split("-")[0].replace("note", "") === ""
```

The simple fix would be to get the second, rather than first, element of the split string:

```
var timerVariable = $(this).attr('id').split("-")[1];
```

To ensure you get a number, you could use a regular expression.

```
var timerId = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/);
if (timerId) {
    timerId=timerId[0];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
var timers = new Array(); 

$('.notes').keyup(function(){ 

    var temp = $(this).attr('id').split("-"); 
    timerValue = temp[0]; 
    timerID = temp[1];
    alert(timerID); // 1192 

    timers[timerID] = timerValue; 
    alert(timers.join('\n'));

});
```

With the way you currently have it, `timerVariable` will be '' in the end, and so what you're doing at the end is really the same as:

```
timers[''] = '';
```